# SlidingTabView inside Toolbar

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, toolbar, transparent

I have a transparent `SlidingTabLayout` embedded within my `Toolbar` and a `ViewPager` below.

Everything works fine, functionally. However, the `SlidingTabLayout` isn't showing up in the bottom left corner of the `Toolbar`. Instead, it is floating in the middle and to the right:

[image]

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/thunderstorm2"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <com.mjh.android.weathertestlayout.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#88ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
        </com.mjh.android.weathertestlayout.SlidingTabLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffcccc">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the accompanying code:

```
adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 3);
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);

tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
@Override
public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
    return getResources().getColor(R.color.gray);
}});
tabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.clear));
tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

Any idea how to get the `SlidingTabLayout` back to the lower left within my `Toolbar`?

I've tried it on numerous devices and emulators, but it remains the same.

Comment: Try nesting SlidingTabLayout inside a linear layout (with match_parent in width and wrap_content in height).

Comment: I've done so and also played with the LinearLayout params but it doesn't change anything that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to nest your `SlidingTabLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`.

Then you can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft` to place it at the bottom-left corner of the `Toolbar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/thunderstorm2"
    android:padding="0dp">

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.mjh.android.weathertestlayout.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#88ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        </com.mjh.android.weathertestlayout.SlidingTabLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffcccc">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```